# Transfer from one wallet to another

Tags: wallets

I stupidly invested in weeCoin (WMA) last year and was advised that I need to buy etherium to use as "gas"

I still have both the WMA tokens and the Etherium I sent showing in the weeWallet but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to transfer the Etherium out of the weeWallet into another wallet.

The weeWallet does not appear to have a section where I can input the address of the wallet I want to transfer to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With the private key or mnemonic phrase try using an Ethereum wallet like MyEthereumWallet or MyCrypto.

Answer (score 0):

congratulations, you probably got scammed. There's not much you can do, except move on.

Comment: Hi, yes I've no doubt it was some sort of a scam.  The bit that's confusing me is when I log into my weeWallet the WMA tokens and the Etherium still show up and intact the value of the etherium seems to be tracking current markets.  The WMA tokens is listed on Probit but the value has dropped considerably.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/51660)

Comment: @Undead8 and answer is between the lines if you read it. but I'll write it for you "you can't transfer from a scammer's wallet to yours" Happy now?